# How to show Miller indexes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text, latex, label

I'm using MATLAB to plot XRD analyses where Miller indexes are used to identify crystallographic plane directions. These indexes contain 3 or 4 numbers and negative value is shown with bar over this number.

In LaTeX it can be written by `\([1\bar{1}1]\)` or `\([1\overline{1}1]\)` command.

For labeling spectral lines of XRD standards I'm using this command: Note that negative values are not considered.

```
std_text_hkl(j)=text(theta{i}(j)-r,0.1,['[' hkl{j} ']'],... % position and label
       of j-th line of i-th standard; hkl{j} holds Miller index in string format
    'parent',ax_std(i),... % association with axes of i-th standard
    'rotation',90,...
    'fontsize',12,...
    'fontname',Font); % Font holds global font setup
```

How can I automate creating bar over negative number without using `'Interpreter','latex'` property since I would like to be able to change `'FontName'`property aswell. At leat I'd like to avoid different fonts in labels and ticks.

EDIT:
Thanks to Magla's comment I got this idea:

- Store indexes as 3 column matrix
- separate label into 5 text fields
- if Miller index is negative draw line over it (top line of text frame)

Actual piece of code:

```
rr=get(ax_std(i),'xlim'); % read x-axis limits of i-th standard
    r=(rr(2)-rr(1))/150; % x-offset of Miller indexes
    for j=1:size(dhkl,1)
      theta{i}(j)=asin(lambda/(2*dhkl(j,1)))*360/pi(); %calculating of lines
                   %positions (Bragg's law)
      line('parent',ax_std(i),...
            'xdata',[theta{i}(j) theta{i}(j)],...
            'ydata',[0 dhkl(j,2)],... % j-th line's reflection intensity
            'color',[colors(1+mod(i-1,size(colors,1)),1:3)],...
            'linewidth',3)

%         Miller indexes

      if theta{i}(j)>rr(1)&&theta{i}(j)<rr(2) % test if line is inside axes
          std_text_lbrace(j)=text(theta{i}(j)-r,0.1,'[',...
            'parent',ax_std(i),...
            'verticalalignment','bottom',...
            'horizontalalignment','left',...
            'rotation',90,...
            'fontsize',12,...
            'fontname',Font);
        pos=get(std_text_lbrace(j),'position');
        ext=get(std_text_lbrace(j),'extent');

        std_text_h(j)=text(pos(1),pos(2)+ext(4)/1.5,int2str(abs(hkl(j,1))),...
            'parent',ax_std(i),...
            'verticalalignment','bottom',...
            'horizontalalignment','left',...
            'rotation',90,...
            'fontsize',12,...
            'fontname',Font); % write 1st Miller index
        pos=get(std_text_h(j),'position');
        ext=get(std_text_h(j),'extent')
        if hkl(j,1)<0 % if negative, draw line over it
            wdth=get(ax0,'xlim');
            wdth=wdth(2)-wdth(1);
            set(std_text_h(j),'color','b','edgecolor','g')
            line('parent',ax_std(i),...
                'xdata',[pos(1)-wdth/280*ext(3),pos(1)-wdth/280*ext(3)],...
                'ydata',[pos(2),pos(2)+ext(4)/wdth*100],...
                'color','r')
        end
      end
```

I can't fit the line length. For single digit it's too long, for two digits it fits and for more (theoretically) it's way too short. What am I doing wrong? How does MATLAB measure `'extent'` property of rotated text?

Comment: I would use an second text field with underscores only, and translate or rotate it to match the target number. This solution works fine with equally spaced font though (courier new, monospaced).

Comment: @Magla: Good point, `'  _  \newline[111]'` should do that trick. But, as you say, only for `fixedwidth` font (there should double spaces).

Comment: Have you cosidered the many answers to "using latex tick labels", e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9328945/2180721. This does not let use any font, but the workaround proposed by Magla applies to your specific request only, and if you have some complex latex to display, using graphical objects will become unfeasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that displays overlines on the top of negative digits. This solution does not use `'interpreter','latex'` so that one may choose different fonts. Note that the code uses a set of single textboxes, each one having a `\n` or `char(10)` to display on the top line the underscore (`char(95)`, or `' '` for positive digits) and on the bottom line the associated number. One can choose to have two different textboxes to set a particular distance between the underscore and its number. This piece of code does not work for all the fonts though (I would say 90% of my system fonts works fine).

The following code

```
%Miller indices
miller_ind = [1 -1 -2 3 -3];

%font definition
c = listfonts;
ind_perm = randperm(length(c));
font_names = {'Arial','Times','Courier New',c{ind_perm}};
font_size = 16;

figure('Color','w','Position',[10 10 600 1000]);
py = 0.05;
for ind_font = 1:12

    %font name
    text(0.03,py,font_names{ind_font},'FontName',font_names{ind_font},'FontSize',font_size);

    %plot miller textbox
    px = 0.6;
    for ii = 1:length(miller_ind)
        if miller_ind(ii)<0
            text(px,py,[char(95) char(10) num2str(-1*miller_ind(ii)) ],...
                'FontName',font_names{ind_font},'FontSize',font_size,'interpreter','none');
        else
            text(px,py,[' ' char(10) num2str(miller_ind(ii)) ],...
                'FontName',font_names{ind_font},'FontSize',font_size,'interpreter','none');
        end
        px = px + 0.03;
    end
    py = py + 0.09;
end
```

gives this result

[image]

**EDIT**
Thank to  @Oleg Komarov for his comment. Picture is now directly saved as a .`tiff` and not via `.eps`.

Comment: What you're actually showing to be different font types are actually the same.

Comment: oops - that's true - at least for the top part of the figure. Fortunately, I added Arial, Courier New, and Times at the bottom part and I can see they show up differently. Edit on its way!

Comment: Actually, all the 12 fonts are correctly written in Matlab's figure. It seems that 'save as eps' didn't work - my bad. Picture edited! Thanks for pointing this out @Oleg Komarov.