# MATLAB putting negative sign above a number in plot text

Tags: matlab

So I want to add text to a plot that is a crystal direction. Sounds easy enough, right?

It's easy to do `[110]`, but what if I want to do `[-110]`? If you are familiar with crystallography, you know that the negative sign should be above the 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called [Miller indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index). You can use LaTeX in Matlab `text` command, so it's pretty straight-forward:

```
figure();
axes();
text(0.5, 0.5, '\([1\bar{1}0]\)', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

[image]

You [can even do that without LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032994/how-to-show-miller-indexes-in-matlab), but there's no point unless you need to e.g. customise font.